# True Type vs. Open Type

Tags: types, fonts, truetype

What is the difference between *true type* and *open type* font? Does the latter suggest openness as in open-source? Does the OS use a different "engine" for rendering those two?

Edit:
Sorry, wasn't really clear in my original question. I was actually looking for more explanation regarding the visual difference (if any) between the two; maybe one has more limitation in the e.g. angles to generate curves, etc.

Comment: Down voting as this is a poor question that could be answered with a simple bit of work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two may use different technologies for describing character outlines. There is no relationship with open source.

TrueType fonts use TrueType outline descriptions, OpenType fonts may use either TrueType outlines or CFF (Compact Font Format) outlines.

Specifications for both formats are published and freely available.

Comment: correction on this explanation, even if it's 7 years late: TrueType is an *outline* specification language, much like CFF and SVG, whereas OpenType is a *typeface* specification. When you see a "ttf" font, it's not a TrueType font, it's an "Opentype *typeface* with TrueType *outlines*", and when you see an "otf" font, it's an "OpenType *typeface* with CFF *outlines*" (also sometimes referred to as OpenType with PostScript outlines, which has never been true, just convenient enough to colloquially work, but as wrong as calling the fonts "opentype" just because the extension is .otf)

Answer (score 1):

A simple [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType)/google search would get you to....

> OpenType is a format for scalable computer fonts. It was built on its
>   predecessor TrueType, retaining TrueType's basic structure and adding
>   many intricate data structures for prescribing typographic behavior.
>   OpenType is a registered trademark of Microsoft Corporation.[2] The
>   specification germinated at Microsoft, with Adobe Systems also
>   contributing by the time of the public announcement in 1996. The
>   specification continues to be developed actively and is presently
>   migrating to an open format. Because of wide availability and
>   typographic flexibility, including provisions for handling the diverse
>   behaviors of all the world's writing systems, OpenType fonts are used
>   commonly today on the major computer platforms.